# How can I specify the download folder for rails system tests using chrome?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium-webdriver

My use case here is twofold:

1. Avoid filling up the standard folder (in my case `~/Downloads`) with files generated by system specs.
2. Ensure unity across build environments when uploading downloaded files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pack the following in your `spec_helper.rb`:

```
config.before(:each, type: :system, js: true) do
  desired_capabilities = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.chrome(
    'chromeOptions' => {
      'prefs' => {
        'download.default_directory' => Rails.root.join('spec/downloads'),
        'download.prompt_for_download' => false,
        'plugins.plugins_disabled' => ["Chrome PDF Viewer"]
      }
    }
  )
  driven_by :selenium, using: :chrome, options: { desired_capabilities: desired_capabilities }
end
```

Et voila!

Answer (score 0):

Latest chrome Ruby have been updated to such

```rb
prefs = {
  prompt_for_download: false, 
  default_directory: "/path/to/dir"
}
options = Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options.new
options.add_preference(:download, prefs)
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome, options: options
```

[source](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/Ruby-Bindings#tweaking-profile-preferences)